# what is ColorPrimaryLight and how do I use it?

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

[image]

I get this as one of my colors generated by the [Material Design Color Platte](https://www.materialpalette.com/deep-purple/light-blue).

But in this image:

[image]

I don't see `colorPrimaryLight` anywhere. What is it used for and how do I declare it? Do declare it like this in my style?:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
```

Or do I declare it in a different way? And what is it used for?

Comment: You can delete it it wull not affect your code if it is not called in any of your XML layouts

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson I am well aware of that, but I'm curious on how to use it as it might be useful on improving my design.

Comment: Let's say you want a button with that color, you go to your button properties and declare it like so : android: background Color ="@color/colorPrimaryLight" you can delete the whole <item> thing as it is alredy saved in the colors file

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson You're kidding, right? I am obviously well aware of that, it's like every single color. But I'm asking what Android uses it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the statusBarColor is set to colorPrimaryDark. If you want to use colorPrimaryLight for the status bar you need to set android:statusBarColor to android:colorPrimaryLight.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

in your resources file put:
`<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#D1C4E9</color>`

in your styles file put:
`<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>`

Comment: So, `colorPrimaryLight` is just a substitute for `colorPrimaryDark`?

Comment: yes, it makes sense sometimes to use a light status bar if your design calls for it or if the dark color makes the status bar information hard to read.

Comment: But then why don't we just change `colorPrimaryDark` to the light color we want?

Comment: You could do that if you want. Typically color palettes have both light and dark colors though. If another dev picked up your code afterwards it might be confusing. But if it's just you, that's an option you could consider. If this helped, please accept my answer. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I'll wait some time before accepting it in case something else comes up :)

Comment: Ok, just make sure somebody gets the points for taking the time to help. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, do you know how to declare `colorPrimaryLight`? `<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121764/discussion-between-joel-nieman-and-abappletic).

Comment: If this answer was ever correct, it isn't now. Adding `<item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>` to styles.xml throws a compile error: `style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryLight (aka com.foobar.themetest:attr/colorPrimaryLight)' not found`

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **colorPrimaryLight** is one of several colors identified as part of the Material palette that is not actually mapped to a Theme attribute in Android. The guidelines recommend using it in several areas such as a TabLayout backgrounds.

I cannot find an authoritative source about using this attribute in Android apps, but it seems that Material defines a large number of colors, [as shown on this helpful page](https://material.io/tools/color), but not all of them are mapped to Android Theme attributes. For instance, if you create a brand new single-Activity project in Android Studio and modify styles.xml as shown below:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!-- THIS THEME ATTRIBUTE IS NOT FOUND -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The **colorPrimaryLight** attribute is not found by the compiler.

Therefore if you wanted to use it in your application you would presumably have to explicitly link to a color.xml resource. This seems to negate the benefit of the Theme system somewhat, but perhaps I am missing a trick.